# C++ Process Reading pointers

Tags: c++, memory, readprocessmemory

i'm trying to read the memory of a game called: "Prison Architect",
but i always have this value: "Money :-858993460"
I lost 2 days without have found any solutions.
I hope you can help me.

---

Pointer Info:

1. BaseAddress: "prison architect.exe"+00075140
2. Pointer1: 300
3. Pointer2: 88
4. Pointer3: 26c
5. Pointer4: 70
6. Pointer5: 328

---

```
int FindPointer(int offset, HANDLE pHandle, int baseaddr, int offsets[])
{
    int Address = baseaddr;
    int total = offset;
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) //Loop trough the offsets
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPCVOID)Address, &Address, 4, NULL);
        Address += offsets[i];
    }
    return Address;
}

int main()
{

    int value = 0; // This will store our value. In my case, its an integer, which is the timer
    DWORD pid; //This will store our Process ID, used to read/write into the memory
    HWND hwnd; //Finally a handle to our window

    hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Prison Architect"); //Finds the Window
    if (!hwnd) //If none, display an error
    {
        cout << "Window not found!\n";
        cin.get();
    }

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid); //Get the process id and place it in pid
    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, pid); //Get permission to read
    if (!phandle) //Once again, if it fails, tell us
    {
        cout << "Could not get handle!\n";
        cin.get();
    }

    int baseAddress = 0x00197BE8;
    int offsets[] = { 0x300, 0x88, 0x26c, 0x70, 0x328 };

    while (1) {

        int moneyRead = FindPointer(5, phandle, baseAddress, offsets); //number of offsets, HANDLE, base address, offsets
        //reading
        int money;
        ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID)moneyRead, &money, sizeof(money), 0);
        cout << "\nMoney :" << money;

        Sleep(3000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that windows will randomize the address. Have you disabled ASLR? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: @drescherjm No,I didn't ,can you give me more info about that ?(code,I mean)

Comment: http://icompile.eladkarako.com/disable-aslr/

Comment: @drescherjm I'll try that. I have another question,there are a lot of software that can read "ProcessMemory" with ASLR and DEP enabled,how can they do that?

Comment: I believe they would not have lines like this `int baseAddress = 0x00197BE8;` instead they would have to detect the base address.

Comment: @drescherjm So if i detect the ImageAddress of "Prison Architect.exe" and then add : "0x00075140"  do i get the BaseAddress? ASLR and DEP can stay enabled? Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

`int baseAddress = 0x00197BE8;`

You're using a hard coded address, which is bad practice because it may only work for this one instance of running the game process.  When you re-open the game it probably will change.

The pointer must begin with an address that has a relative offset from a module.  You then add the relative offset to the address of the module which you have calculated at run time.  This will make it so your final address that is calculated always works correctly, regardless of ASLR.

You can use this function to find the base address of a module

```cpp
uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const wchar_t* modName)
{
    uintptr_t modBaseAddr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_wcsicmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}
```

Add the relative offset to the return value and use this as the base address of the pointer you pass into your FindPointer() function.